# Can't get past Welcome to Jboss page Openshift

Tags: jboss, openshift

I'm trying to use Openshift to host my java webapps.  The problem I am running into is every time I go to my application "http://omniticketmvc-leviliester.rhcloud.com/" it takes me to a "Welcome to your JBossEWS (Apache/Tomcat) application on OpenShift".

I thought maybe it was because my project had some sort of default .war that was being deployed instead of the one I wanted.  To try to confirm that I followed this guide made by to deploy a pre-compiled War file. https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear .

As you can imagine that did not work.  The guide implies that I should be able to find my webapp running at app-domain.rhcloud.com/mywebsite with "mywebsite" being the name of the war file my project created.  In this scenario my Application war file is name "OmniTicket".  I can find that war file on the server using ssh but the directory hierarchy is confusing to me.

I also tried looking in logs on the server but I don't see any errors to indicate a malfunction in spring or database connections.  Any help would be appreciated.  Specifically when I deploy my application to the Jboss Server without any obvious errors, why can't I get to the application root?

I should also mention it is a SpringMVC restful service application that works locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

1. Rename your war name to ROOT.war
2. Delete the src and pom.xml. If pom.xml is present then OpenShift would try to build the maven project
3. Place the war in deployments folder under your application root folder
4. Commit the war and push changes to application Git repository.
5. Check the logs using rhc tail command